# LTS Enablement Stack on Trusty has unmet depencies

Tags: 14.04, hardware-enablement-stack

I have **Ubuntu 14.04** (kernel 3.19.0-49) and I would like to install the latest LTS Enablement Stack to access kernel 4+.

According to the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), I need to do

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily 


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-lts-wily : Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-wily but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libgles2-mesa-lts-wily but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libgles1-mesa-lts-wily but it is not going to be installed
                         Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx (>= 0~)
                         Conflicts: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~)
                         Conflicts: libgles2-mesa (>= 0~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

but I am experiencing unmet dependecies.

Why? What should I do?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately, I can't install the recommended packages alone.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily
[...]
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily : Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-wily (= 11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-wily (>= 7.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

And if I try to install

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa-lts-wily

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily : Conflicts: libglapi-mesa
                          Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386
```

---

**EDIT-2:**

Unfortunately, with the LTE HWE installed the system does not start. It hangs on boot and does not proceed to the login screen.

I "solved" by reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04.4 from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command is

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libglapi-mesa-lts-wily libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386
```

That "official" wiki is always wrong.

And also be aware that you do not HAVE to upgrade `xserver-xorg` if you want the 4.2 kernel. You can upgrade just kernel by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, unfortunately, with the LTE HWE installed the system does not start. It hangs on boot and does not proceed to the login screen. I "solved" by reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04.4 from scratch.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me when I have just a blank screen after installing what wiki said! I don't trust anymore to wiki!

Answer (score 0):

First, (be careful here) delete the offending packages and then run the install:

```
sudo apt-get purge libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2-mesa:i386 
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-wily libgles2-mesa-lts-wily linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily libgles1-mesa-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily
```

If you also need the i386 versions, run this as well:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-wily:i386 libgles2-mesa-lts-wily:i386 linux-generic-lts-wily:i386 xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily:i386 xserver-xorg-lts-wily:i386 libgles1-mesa-lts-wily:i386 xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily:i386 xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily
```

---

or just install without the recommends:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily
```

Comment: @Claudio I have updated the answer. What I mean by "be careful" is, pay attention to what will be uninstalled and do not accept the changes if it wants to uninstall a whole bunch of other stuff that you want to keep. If the list of packages to uninstall is short, take note of the list and accept the changes.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, unfortunately, with the LTE HWE installed the system does not start. It hangs on boot and does not proceed to the login screen. I "solved" by reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04.4 from scratch.

Comment: @Claudio What, did you install nvidia from source or something?

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Solved by removing libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic and libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic first:

```
sudo apt-get purge libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic
```

And then installed by wiki instruction.